# Properties That Depend on Another Watched Property

Tags: angularjs

These *appear* to work the same.  But are they the same? (note $scope.active)

**First one:**

```
angular.module('my.controllers', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myService',
function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.myFilters = myService.myFilters;
    $scope.active = $scope.myFilters.length > 0;
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return myService.myFilters;
    }, function(newFilters) {
        $scope.myFilters = newFilters;
        $scope.active = $scope.myFilters.length > 0;
    },true);
}]);
```

**Second one:**

```
angular.module('my.controllers', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myService',
function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.myFilters = myService.myFilters;
    $scope.active = function(){return $scope.myFilters.length > 0};
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return myService.myFilters;
    }, function(newFilters) {
        $scope.myFilters = newFilters;
    },true);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding to `active` in HTML in the second scenario, it will be called **on every apply-digest cycle**, because the result of the function is unknown until called. This gives you two differences: changes to `$scope.myFilters.length` after the controller function has run, will not be reflected in the binding in the first scenario (if you do not update the value yourself), and there will be a (albeit minimal) performance hit in the second scenario due to the function being called **at least** once every apply-digest cycle.